# Убрать отступ слева в LeftToRight QListWidget

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, qlayout, pyside6

Мне требуется убрать отступ указанный на скрине красной линией (слева).

Как это можно реализовать?

Я пытался использовать`setSpacing`, но это не дало должного результата.

И дополнительно, если можно было бы неплохо узнать как убрать белый квадрат выделения вокруг виджета. (Скриншот 2)

Скриншот 1
[image: Что я хочу]
Скриншот2

[image: Выделение]

МВП:

```py
import sys

from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QLayout, QSizePolicy,
                               QSpacerItem, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QMainWindow, QListView, QAbstractItemView,
                               QListWidget, QFrame, QGridLayout)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(179, 305)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QSize(179, 0))
        Form.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        Form.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(37, 41, 49)")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(2)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetFixedSize)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.imagelabel = QLabel(Form)
        self.imagelabel.setObjectName(u"imagelabel")
        self.imagelabel.setMinimumSize(QSize(179, 256))
        self.imagelabel.setMaximumSize(QSize(179, 256))

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.imagelabel)

        self.nameru = QLabel(Form)
        self.nameru.setObjectName(u"nameru")
        self.nameru.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 50))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamilies([u"Segoe UI Black"])
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.nameru.setFont(font)
        self.nameru.setStyleSheet(u"color: rgb(241, 241, 241);\n"
"font-size: 10pt;\n"
"font-family: Segoe UI Black\n"
"")
        self.nameru.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.nameru.setWordWrap(True)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.nameru)

        self.nameen = QLabel(Form)
        self.nameen.setObjectName(u"nameen")
        self.nameen.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 30))
        font1 = QFont()
        font1.setFamilies([u"Segoe UI"])
        font1.setPointSize(8)
        self.nameen.setFont(font1)
        self.nameen.setStyleSheet(u"color: #626a76;\n"
"font-size: 8pt;\n"
"font-family: Segoe UI\n"
"")
        self.nameen.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.nameen.setWordWrap(True)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.nameen)

        self.verticalSpacer = QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.verticalLayout.addItem(self.verticalSpacer)


        self.retranslateUi(Form)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
    # setupUi
    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.imagelabel.setText("")
        self.nameru.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"TEST", None))
        self.nameen.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"TEST:\n"
"Beiketushen", None))

class LinkedWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LinkedWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.imagedata = None


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(864, 346)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(37, 41, 49)")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.linkedframe = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.linkedframe.setObjectName(u"linkedframe")
        self.linkedframe.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 50))
        self.linkedframe.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.linkedframe.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_23 = QVBoxLayout(self.linkedframe)
        self.verticalLayout_23.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_23.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_23")
        self.verticalLayout_23.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.linkedlabel = QLabel(self.linkedframe)
        self.linkedlabel.setObjectName(u"linkedlabel")
        self.linkedlabel.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 30))
        self.linkedlabel.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.linkedlabel.setStyleSheet(u"color: rgb(241, 241, 241);\n"
"font-size: 14pt;\n"
"font-family: Segoe UI Black\n"
"")

        self.verticalLayout_23.addWidget(self.linkedlabel)

        self.linkedlistwidget = QListWidget(self.linkedframe)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setObjectName(u"linkedlistwidget")
        self.linkedlistwidget.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 168))
        self.linkedlistwidget.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setStyleSheet(u"QListWidget{\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"}\n"
"QListWidget::item{\n"
"    margin: 5px;\n"
"    background-color: transparent; \n"
"    border: 0px;\n"
"    padding-left: 1px;\n"
"}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected{\n"
"background-color: transparent;\n"
"}\n"
"QListWidget::item:hover{\n"
"    background-color: transparent; \n"
"}")
        self.linkedlistwidget.setFrameShape(QFrame.Panel)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setHorizontalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setMovement(QListView.Static)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setFlow(QListView.LeftToRight)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setProperty("isWrapping", True)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setResizeMode(QListView.Fixed)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setLayoutMode(QListView.SinglePass)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setSpacing(0)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setViewMode(QListView.ListMode)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setWordWrap(True)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setSelectionRectVisible(False)

        self.verticalLayout_23.addWidget(self.linkedlistwidget)


        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.linkedframe, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.linkedlabel.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u0432\u044f\u0437\u0430\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0435", None))
    # retranslateUi

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setSpacing(0)
        for i in range(0, 5):
            linkedwidget = LinkedWidget()
            linkedwidget.nameru.setText("TEST")
            linkedwidget.nameen.setText("TEST")
            movie = QtGui.QMovie("loading.gif") # можете заменить другой гифкой или чем либо ещё
            size = QSize(179, 256)
            movie.setScaledSize(size)
            linkedwidget.imagelabel.setMovie(movie)
            movie.start()
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.linkedlistwidget)
            item.setSizeHint(linkedwidget.sizeHint())
            self.linkedlistwidget.addItem(item)
            self.linkedlistwidget.setItemWidget(item, linkedwidget)
            self.linkedlistwidget.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, item.sizeHint().height()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        self.linkedlistwidget.setStyleSheet(u"QListWidget{\n"
        
#"    padding: 5px;\n"                                                         # <---- ---
"    padding: 0px;\n"                                                          # <---- +++

"    outline: none;"                                                           # <---- +++

"}\n"
"QListWidget::item{\n"

#"    margin: 5px;\n"                                                          # <---- ---
"    margin: 0px;\n"                                                           # <---- +++


"    background-color: transparent; \n"
"    border: 0px;\n"
"    padding-left: 1px;\n"
"}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected{\n"
"background-color: transparent;\n"
"}\n"
"QListWidget::item:hover{\n"
"    background-color: transparent; \n"
"}")
```

---

```
import sys
'''
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QLayout, QSizePolicy,
                               QSpacerItem, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QMainWindow, QListView, QAbstractItemView,
                               QListWidget, QFrame, QGridLayout)
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(179, 305)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QSize(179, 0))
        Form.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        Form.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(37, 41, 49)")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(2)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetFixedSize)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.imagelabel = QLabel(Form)
        self.imagelabel.setObjectName(u"imagelabel")
        self.imagelabel.setMinimumSize(QSize(179, 256))
        self.imagelabel.setMaximumSize(QSize(179, 256))

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.imagelabel)

        self.nameru = QLabel(Form)
        self.nameru.setObjectName(u"nameru")
        self.nameru.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 50))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamilies([u"Segoe UI Black"])
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.nameru.setFont(font)
        self.nameru.setStyleSheet(u"color: rgb(241, 241, 241);\n"
"font-size: 10pt;\n"
"font-family: Segoe UI Black\n"
"")
        self.nameru.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.nameru.setWordWrap(True)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.nameru)

        self.nameen = QLabel(Form)
        self.nameen.setObjectName(u"nameen")
        self.nameen.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 30))
        font1 = QFont()
        font1.setFamilies([u"Segoe UI"])
        font1.setPointSize(8)
        self.nameen.setFont(font1)
        self.nameen.setStyleSheet(u"color: #626a76;\n"
"font-size: 8pt;\n"
"font-family: Segoe UI\n"
"")
        self.nameen.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.nameen.setWordWrap(True)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.nameen)

        self.verticalSpacer = QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.verticalLayout.addItem(self.verticalSpacer)


        self.retranslateUi(Form)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
    # setupUi
    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.imagelabel.setText("")
        self.nameru.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"TEST", None))
        self.nameen.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"TEST:\n"
"Beiketushen", None))

class LinkedWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LinkedWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.imagedata = None


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(864, 346)
# ---->                                             ---->1    1  <----
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(137, 141, 49)")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
# +++         
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("#centralwidget {background-color: rgb(137, 41, 49)}")
        
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        
        
        self.linkedframe = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.linkedframe.setObjectName(u"linkedframe")
        self.linkedframe.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 50))
        self.linkedframe.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.linkedframe.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        
        self.verticalLayout_23 = QVBoxLayout(self.linkedframe)
        self.verticalLayout_23.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_23.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_23")
        self.verticalLayout_23.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.linkedlabel = QLabel(self.linkedframe)
        self.linkedlabel.setObjectName(u"linkedlabel")
        self.linkedlabel.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 30))
        self.linkedlabel.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.linkedlabel.setStyleSheet(u"color: rgb(241, 241, 241);\n"
"font-size: 14pt;\n"
"font-family: Segoe UI Black\n"
"")
        self.verticalLayout_23.addWidget(self.linkedlabel)
        

        self.linkedlistwidget = QListWidget(self.linkedframe)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setObjectName(u"linkedlistwidget")
        self.linkedlistwidget.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 168))
        self.linkedlistwidget.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        
        self.linkedlistwidget.setStyleSheet(u"QListWidget{\n"
        
#"    padding: 5px;\n"                                                         # <---- ---
"    padding: 0px;\n"                                                          # <---- +++

"    outline: none;"                                                           # <---- +++

"}\n"
"QListWidget::item{\n"

#"    margin: 5px;\n"                                                          # <---- ---
"    margin: 0px;\n"                                                           # <---- +++


"    background-color: transparent; \n"
"    border: 0px;\n"
"    padding-left: 1px;\n"
"}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected{\n"
"background-color: transparent;\n"
"}\n"
"QListWidget::item:hover{\n"
"    background-color: transparent; \n"
"}")
        
        
        self.linkedlistwidget.setFrameShape(QFrame.Panel)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setHorizontalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setMovement(QListView.Static)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setFlow(QListView.LeftToRight)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setProperty("isWrapping", True)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setResizeMode(QListView.Fixed)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setLayoutMode(QListView.SinglePass)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setSpacing(0)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setViewMode(QListView.ListMode)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setWordWrap(True)
        self.linkedlistwidget.setSelectionRectVisible(False)

        self.verticalLayout_23.addWidget(self.linkedlistwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.linkedframe, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.linkedlabel.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u0432\u044f\u0437\u0430\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0435", None))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

# ---->                                  1        
        self.linkedlistwidget.setSpacing(1)
        
        for i in range(0, 5):
            linkedwidget = LinkedWidget()
            linkedwidget.nameru.setText("TEST")
            linkedwidget.nameen.setText("TEST")
            movie = QtGui.QMovie("loading.gif") # можете заменить другой гифкой или чем либо ещё
            size = QSize(179, 256)
            movie.setScaledSize(size)
            linkedwidget.imagelabel.setMovie(movie)
            movie.start()
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.linkedlistwidget)
            item.setSizeHint(linkedwidget.sizeHint())
            self.linkedlistwidget.addItem(item)
            self.linkedlistwidget.setItemWidget(item, linkedwidget)
            self.linkedlistwidget.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, item.sizeHint().height()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, это решило проблему